# Installing seaborn on Pycharm with Python3.5 - now nothing runs

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, seaborn

I have been working on coding in a Pycharm environment today, and everything was working fine. Then, I installed the `seaborn` package, and imported `matplotlib` and `seaborn`. Before I did these two things, everything was working fine, and I have used `matplotlib` many times before. So the issue lies in `seaborn` I imagine.

Now, no matter what project I run, I get a number of error messages, including:

```
ImportError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'
```

in a couple of instances.

Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong here? I have already tried upgrading all relevant packages and pip, and have uninstalled and reinstalled pip. But no luck so far. I apologize if my formatting is incorrect, I don't tend to post on this site, but this issue is driving me up the wall.

Comment: Hint about `ImportError: No module named '__builtin__'`: module `'__builtin__'` is from Python 2; the error means that you're trying to run Python 2 code under Python 3.

Comment: I am confused about why this would make all my previously working code no longer work though? Projects that I successfully ran before now have those same errors.

Comment: Because code that imports module `'__builtin__'` was embedded in some popular module imported from everywhere.

Comment: The funny thing is that seaborn itself should be version independent, i.e. there is only one seaborn version which runs with both python2 and python3. In that sense it is doubtable that the install of seaborn would have caused this.

Comment: The thing is, everything worked fine before I installed seaborn. That being said, I have just checked my code on the command line, and it runs with no errors. So the issue lies in PyCharm.